# having trouble with the code not working with raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mu

```
enter code here
led = LED(17)
led.off()

player_1 = Button(2)
player_2 = Button(3)

time = random.uniform(2, 5)
sleep(time)
led.on()
twoscore = 0
onescore = 0

restart = True

while restart == True:
    restart = False
    if player_1.is_pressed:
        onescore += 1
        print("player one score: " + str(onescore))
        led.off()
        restart = True
    if player_2.is_pressed:
        twoscore += 1
        print("player two score: " + str(twoscore))
        led.off()
        restart = True
```

when the button is pressed the LED does not go off
is it a problem with the while loop?
moredetailmoredetailsmoredetails

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the lines:

```
while restart == True:
    restart = False
```

Restart is set to False and then your code exits the loop immediately after the first iteration.

Try something like:

```
restart = True

while restart == True:
    if player_1.is_pressed:
        onescore += 1
        print("player one score: " + str(onescore))
        led.off()
        restart = False
    if player_2.is_pressed:
        twoscore += 1
        print("player two score: " + str(twoscore))
        led.off()
        restart = False
```

Let me know if that works.

Better still you could write:

```
while True:
    if player_1.is_pressed:
        onescore += 1
        print("player one score: " + str(onescore))
        led.off()
        break
    if player_2.is_pressed:
        twoscore += 1
        print("player two score: " + str(twoscore))
        led.off()
        break
```

Is this what you wish to happen?

Comment: Going to try it now, Thanks!

Comment: With the second one, I don't want to end the code but make a scoring system instead. does break end the code or the while loop?

Comment: It just ends the while loop - it 'breaks' out of the loop